# What can I buy at radio shack to serve as a power switch for my desktop computer?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-rec, case

I have a desktop computer without a case. The parts are strewn across my desk. My motherboard is a gigabyte MA78LMT-S2. There isn't a power button on this motherboard like I've seen on most motherboards. I need to rig up some kind of switch in order to power the computer on.

I'm looking for suggestions on what to buy at radio shack in order to turn the computer on. Is it enough just to short the two 5v power pins on the motherboard with a switch? Is it safe to just attach wires to the pins and short them with my fingers? I was at radio shack today and nothing jumped out at me. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Despite the title, I don't think this actually was a shopping question in the sense that makes shopping questions undesired on stackexchange websites.  That kind of question is undesirable because it goes out of date rapidly.  This question does not fall into that category.

Comment: Use a momentary switch connected to the 2 pins......http://www.radioshack.com/search/index.jsp?kwCatId=&kw=momentary%20switch&origkw=momentary+switch&sr=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A metal screwdriver. You'll need to determine which two pins to jump, but that is fairly easy as they're often silkscreen with codes. Look for something like `PWR+` and then bridge to ground (will be directly next to it)

Comment: ok so once I connect the two pins with a screwdriver, I can remove the screwdriver and the computer will stay on?

Comment: Yep, that's why they use a normally open momentary contact switch for this.

Comment: This is how I turn on my computer.  Putting a case over it is too much work as I'm plugging stuff in all the time.

Comment: i've also used coins, paperclips....

Answer (score 2):

[Gigabyte Manual page 22](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-ma78lmt-s2%28h%29_e.pdf) The switch is a **normally open** spst switch. **Momentary contact** between the pins will give the motherboard a startup command for it to power on. In the front panel a 6mm SMT or through hole NO switch like an [Omron B3F](http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-b3f.pdf) is normally used. These are low current.

For airboard testing, I used to take a two connector LED cable, clip off the LED, solder on a Normally Open push-button switch and run some heat shrink over the contacts. It's best if you use something like this as giving it a quick tap with a paperclip or a jumper might not be so good if you short several pins (and the wrong ones) together, eh? You know which two pins are the power and it's easier to make sure the connector is only on those two pins. A switch I'd use for this test power button is a common Alco switch [similar to this Radio Shack offering](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062546) because it easily fits inside a common heat shrink size, leaving you a nice handle to hold for pressing the button.